# Disable (and re-enable) the href and onclick on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I just want to enable / disable `onclick` and href on elements (a or div).

I don't know how to do this.

I can disable `onclick` by adding an handler on click event, but the href is still available.

```
 
$(this).unbind().click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     return;
});
```

**Edit** FOUND A HACK FOR A ELEMENTS

```
if ($(this).attr("href")) {
     $(this).attr("x-href", $(this).attr("href"));
     $(this).removeAttr("href");
}
```

Comment: It's a pretty vague question. What is it exactly you're trying to do? Remove the `href` property as well?

Comment: Ok, sorry ;) I just want to be able (by clicking on a button), to disable / enable all the links (click or href) over elements (div or a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i've found a workaround : putting an overlay over the main div containing all the elements i wanted to disable ..
It just works.

Comment: Or use the $("#divId").hide(); $("#divId").show(); Thank you for the idea ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you return `false` on the onclick event, the `href` is irgnored.

1. This will go to Goole: `<a
   href="http://www.google.com"
   onclick="alert('Go to
   Google')">Test</a>`
2. This will not go to Google: `<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="alert('Go to Google'); return false;">Test</a>`

Comment: the second line should be: <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="alert('Go to Google');return false;">Test</a>

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
$('a, div').click(
    function(e){
    return false;
        // cancels default action *and* stops propagation

    // or e.preventDefault;
       // cancels default action without stopping propagation
});
```

[MDC documentation for `preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault), [jQuery documentation for `event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

[SO question: JavaScript `event.preventDefault` vs `return false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

I'm unsure as to the problem of the "`href` still being available," since the `click` event is cancelled; however if you want to remove the `href` from `a` elements:

```
$('a[href]').attr('href','#');
```

will remove them (or, rather, replace the URL with a `#`).

---

**Edited** in response to comment (to question) by OP:

> Ok, sorry ;) I just want to be able (by clicking on a button), to disable / enable all the links (click or href) over elements (div or a)

```
$('#buttonRemoveClickId, .buttonClassName').click(
function() {
    $('a, div').unbind('click');
});
$('#buttonReplaceClickId, .buttonOtherClassName').click(
function() {
    $('a, div').bind('click');
});
```

- [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/),
- [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: I've found a solution for the a elements (which consist of placing the href value into a x-href attributes to re-enable it).
But how can I re-enable the onclick handler ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to disable click:

$(this).unbind('click');

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `href` attribute directly to `""` to prevent the original from showing up in the status bar, if that's what you're asking.

```
$(this).unbind().click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
}).attr("href", "");
```

Otherwise, a `event.preventDefault()` already stops links from being clickable.