# How do I select this div and make an animation run when a link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate, bind

How do I select the div  with the link in and make an animation run when the link is clicked?

Here is the html code and script:

```
<div class="section white" id="work">
<div class="maincontent2"></div>
<section class="main">  
            <ul class="ch-grid">
                <li>
                    <div class="ch-item">               
                        <div class="ch-info">
                            <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-1"></div>
                            <div class="ch-info-back" id="graphiccircle">
                                <h3><a href="index.html#graphicdesign">Graphic Design</a></h3>
                                <p>Graphic/Typography<a href="index.html#graphicdesign">View</a></p>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
</ul>

        </section>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$(function() {
            $('').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                 $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left, scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Comment: You are binding to `''`, which is not very likely to do much. Can you set up a jsFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: In general, returning false from the event handler should prevent the navigation from happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625893/disable-and-re-enable-the-href-and-onclick-on-elements

Comment: Yes I've left this blank because I do not know how to define the div class with the <a href> in, this is the problem I have been having.

Comment: There are more problems, e.g. `$($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left` looking up the href in the current document will not find a match, so the `offset()` fails. Changing that to simply `$(this).offset()` gets it further: http://jsfiddle.net/XT7E8/

Comment: I've tested the code on a simple id div with a link in and it works fine

Comment: To select the anchor in this fragment, I simply used this selector: `$('h3 a')`, but there are many others that work too. It depends on the rest of your HTML.